# Separating 3 Different Values From Same Input

Tags: c#

In c# how to separate and sum 3 different value entered from same input?
For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Points For Student");
```

And the input will be like: 3.5 2.5 4

With that input I want to have this result: 11

And I want to print to screen

Comment: I assume the wanted value of 11 is a type, as the values summed together = 10!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input by the separating char, which in your case is a space.
Then loop through and sum the values.

```
string input = "3.5 2.5 4";

float res = 0;   
//Loop through each input separated by space
foreach (string str in input.Split(' '))
{
    float tmp = 0;  //temporary value
    //Only sum if the value  is a valid float value
    if (float.TryParse(str, out tmp))
      res += tmp;
}
Console.WriteLine($"Result = {res}");
```

Comment: It's working great but my question was as an example I need to split 3 of that value because. input1="2 3 4" input2="5 6 7". I need to sum 2+5 3+6 4+7 I need it in that format. Sorry for example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear how do you get the inputs. Assuming you `Console.ReadLine();` two string  variables named `input1` and `input2` where:

```cs
input1 = "2 3 4";
input2 = "5 6 7";
```

... and you want to sum the corresponding numbers (2+5, 3+6, 4+7). One way to achieve that is through the [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to split the inputs and create two sequences of `int` type from the substrings, [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip%60%603);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) them to sum the corresponding numbers or addends and return a result sequence.

```cs
var arrSum = input1
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .Zip(input2
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(y => int.TryParse(y, out _))
    .Select(y => int.Parse(y)), (x, y) => x + y);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", arrSum));
```

The output is:

```
7
9
11
```

If you'd like to get the equation of each sum operation:

```cs
var strSum = input1
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .Zip(input2
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(y => int.TryParse(y, out _))
    .Select(y => int.Parse(y)), (x, y) => $"{x} + {y} = {x + y}");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strSum));
```

The outcome:

```
2 + 5 = 7
3 + 6 = 9
4 + 7 = 11
```

If there is a possibility to have inputs with non equal elements such as:

```
input1 = "2 3 4";
input2 = "5 6";

//or

input1 = "2 3";
input2 = "5 6 7";
```

Then use `for..loop` instead as follows:

```cs
var arr1 = input1.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var arr2 = input2.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for (var i = 0; i < Math.Max(arr1.Length, arr2.Length); i++)
{
    var sum = 0;
    if (i < arr1.Length && int.TryParse(arr1[i], out int x))
        sum = x;
    if (i < arr2.Length && int.TryParse(arr2[i], out int y))
        sum += y;
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```